# Using jQuery and JavaScript to create rows and cells in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been browsing around google and stack overflow to find an answer, but I'd like to get a direct answer to my question, thus the post.

So, I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery, so pardon any ridiculousness haha.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  getGridSize();

});


function getGridSize() {
  sizeWidth = parseInt(prompt("Width?"));
  sizeHeight = parseInt(prompt("Height?"));
  fillGrid(sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
}

function fillGrid(width, height) {
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    $('table').append("<tr></tr>");
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      $('tr').append("<td><div></div></td>")
    };
  };
}
```

The above is what I have in my .js file currently. I'm using a skeleton html file with an empty `<table> </table>` in the body.

What I'm trying to do is create a "width" and "height" of a table and fill in `<div>` in each cell. I have a css file to change the `<div>` files into small squares with black borders.

I saw a tutorial recently by Helping Develop where they create a slider script with jQuery and JS. The code really reminded me of a class element in Ruby using the `$(document).ready(function()` block as an initialize.

My initial attempt at this project is an emulation of what I saw and what I've experienced with Ruby. However, it didn't turn out as expected and I'd like to get some feedback on what I've written so far.

Anyways, all constructive criticism welcome. Is it ok to think of the jQuery `ready` block as a similar function to an `initialize` method in Ruby? Any no-no's you see here that I should avoid in the future? Any helpful nudges in the right direction please?  :)

Edit: I think I've caught an error with my  and  creations. Will edit once testing it out.

Edit2: Ok, my other attempt didn't work out. :( still seeking help

Comment: I would recommend doing this in a template based framework like knockoutJS, AngularJS or similar. Dynamic html via javascript/jquery is not a very maintainable pattern.

Comment: @TGH mvvc frameworks aren't exactly entry level javascript

Comment: knockout has a very good tutorial and can be learnt in a reasonably beginner level http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: I will definitely checkout AngularJS and maybe knockoutJS in the near future, but I'd like to stick with just jQuery and JS for this problem. I'm doing this problem for learning purposes only. Thanks for the replies, bookmarked the link you gave Eduardo :)

Comment: As far as I know, Angular is better than knockoutJS (more capabilities), the only reason I usually recommend knockout is because I've gone through both of their pages and knockout was ridiculously fast to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the function `fillGrid` to this.

```
function fillGrid(width, height) {
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {

      var tr= $("<tr>");
      for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        tr.append("<td><div>test</div></td>");
      };
      var table = $("<table>");
      table.append(tr);
      $(document.body).append(table);
    };
  }
```

Check plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ukgIa7W640k9voQu3Qs?p=preview).

Note: I have added sample text **test** so that you can see the table.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I have some questions about the solution though. How can we store `var tr = $("<tr>");` the first time when we don't have any table rows initially made? Same with appending the table cells into the table row.  // Also, using `document.body`, will this create a brand new table? If I wanted to edit an existing table, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Thats the magic of JQuery, the element need not be present in the document.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with

```
function fillGrid(width, height) {
    var htm = "";
  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      htm += "<tr>";

      for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
          htm += "<td></td>"
      };
      htm += "</tr>"
  };
    $("table").html(htm);
}
```

But please don't, this is a terrible practice and there are much easier ways to handle dynamic content in pages, I'd highly recommend you to learn [knockout.js](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) if you want to handle this type of thing properly, and I find it's tutorial to be particularly good compared to most other tools so it's not too much of a hassle to go through it

Comment: Thank you Eduardo. Just curious, would knockout.js be a good precursor to learning angular.js?

Comment: I Don't know because I quit web development while I was learning angular.js (switched to another company), but knockout made me understand a little bit about bindings and now I can't live without them in any UI framework I use.